# Better way of using the redirection symbol in conjunction with find -exec

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find

My goal is to empty every file in a directory. I DON'T want to actually delete the file, I just want to delete it's contents.

If you want to do this with a single file you can do `> file.txt`

If I want to run this operation on every file in a directory I can do this:

```
find . -exec /bin/bash -c '> {}' \;
```

Notice how the above command has to call `/bin/bash`. This is because simply running the command like this, `find . -exec > {} \;` says `find: invalid argument ;' to -exec'` I suspect this is because the redirection symbol is confusing the command.

I would like to run this command without needing to run `/bin/bash` within `-exec`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this is by using `truncate`:

```
find -type f -exec truncate -s0 {} +
```

If you want to only use bash, you could use a `while` loop:

```
find -type f -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        > "$file"
    done
```

Finally, if you didn't mind using `bash -c`, it would be better to do it as follows to avoid calling bash so many times:

```
find -type f -exec bash -c 'for file; do > "$file"; done' - {} +
```

although I don't like that solution.

Comment: Nice one. The first one is perfect. What does `-s0` do? I couldn't find any information on it.

Comment: `-s0` means: truncate the file to 0 bytes.

Comment: Funny that the solution you don't like is more idiomatic (and portable) than the `find`-with-`-print0` one.